# XML API Children Return Function?

Tags: c#, jquery, xml

I'm performing an API call to a controller that returns XML. The output is:

```
<ArrayOfreport_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>United States</label>
        <value>65</value>
    </report_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>United Kingdom</label>
        <value>58</value>
    </report_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>Germany</label>
        <value>30</value>
    </report_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>India</label>
        <value>65</value>
    </report_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>Russia</label>
        <value>65</value>
    </report_overallTime>
    <report_overallTime>
        <label>Germany</label>
        <value>30</value>
    </report_overallTime>
</ArrayOfreport_overallTime>
```

This is generated from the following C# controller code:

```
public class report_overallTimeController : ApiController
{
    public void report_overallTime(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
        GetAllItems();
    }

    report_overallTime[] items = new report_overallTime[]
    {
        new report_overallTime { label = "United States", value = "65" },
        new report_overallTime { label = "United Kingdom", value = "58" },
        new report_overallTime { label = "Germany", value = "30" },
        new report_overallTime { label = "India", value = "65" },
        new report_overallTime { label = "Russia", value = "65" },
        new report_overallTime { label = "Germany", value = "30" }
    };

    public IEnumerable<report_overallTime> GetAllItems()
    {
        return items;
    }       
}
```

In my jQuery, I'm attempting to get the label/value pairs and insert them into an array.

```
function initChart(xml) {
    var data = [];
    //alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
    $(xml).find('ArrayOfreport_overallTime report_overallTime').each(function (index) {
        var label = $(this).children("label").text;
        var value = $(this).children("value").text;
        data.push([label, parseFloat(value)]);
    });
    //Do something with data...
}
```

When I try to output the values of var label, I get the following on my alert:

```
function(a) {
    return Y(this, function(a) {
        return void 0 === a ? n.text(this) : this.empty().append((this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || d).createTextNode(a))
    }, null, a, arguments.length)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am expecting to be alerted with the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `ArrayOfreport_overallTime` element is the root of the XML string, so you need to use `filter()` to retrieve that, then `find()` to get the `report_overallTime`. You can also use `map()` to build your array. Try this:

```js
var xml = '<ArrayOfreport_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>United States</label><value>65</value></report_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>United Kingdom</label><value>58</value></report_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>Germany</label><value>30</value></report_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>India</label><value>65</value></report_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>Russia</label><value>65</value></report_overallTime><report_overallTime><label>Germany</label><value>30</value></report_overallTime></ArrayOfreport_overallTime>';

var data = $(xml).filter('ArrayOfreport_overallTime').find('report_overallTime').map(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return [[$el.children("label").text(), parseFloat($el.children("value").text())]];
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: var data no longer returns a function, but now returns an empty array:  []

Comment: Your original version returned functions as you used `text`, not `text()`. However as you can see from the fiddle, this works given the XML you provided. Can you show a sample of the non-working code in a fiddle so I can see how the logic is structured.

Comment: That was it! I just changed text to text() and voila! It worked! Thanks for the tip.